# How to dynamically set a control using variables C#

Tags: c#, .net, properties, set, controls

How do you dynamically call a control and set it property at runtime?

```
// Declare and set queue servers
string[] queueservers = new string[] { "SERVER1", "SERVER2", "SERVER3", "SERVER4" };
int y;

for (y = 0; y <= queueservers.Length - 1; y++)
{
   string queueanswer = GetMailQueueSize(queueservers[y]);
   if (queueanswer == "alarm")
   {
      phxQueueImg + queueservers + .ImageUrl = "~/images/Small-Down.gif";
   }
   else
   {
      phxQueueImg + queueservers + .ImageUrl = "~/images/Small-Up.gif";
   }
   queueanswer = "";
}
```

Comment: Huh? I really don't understand what you're asking here.

Comment: I suspect you just want to *get* a control given then *name* of the control -- if this is the case, I would advise using a `Dictionary<name,Control>` or similar (although perhaps the general design is icky?) The Controls collection can be manually iterated -- but more ick.

Answer (score 1):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) about asking good questions .

I'm going to assume you pasted the wrong code since it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question afaik. Plus could edit your question and tag if this is winform, wpf or web?

Here I dynamically create the control at runtime:

```
Textbox c = new Textbox();
```

Set its text, eg

```
string s = "Please paste code that relates to your question";
c.Text = s;
```

Or here I dynamically set my textbox controls property using variables:

```
propertyInfo = c.GetType().GetProperty(property); 
if (propertyInfo != null)
{
    propertyInfo.SetValue(c, value, null);
}
```

Comment: I know I'm a little late to the party but that last block just helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

try `FindControl("controlID")` and then cast the result of this call to the required control type and set the needed property.

`(SomeParentControl.FindControl("IDOfControlToFind") AS LinkButton).PostBackUrl = "~/someresource.aspx";`